# How can I disable basic authentication on Tomcat 5.5.27

Tags: basic-authentication

Please let me know how can I disable basic authentication on Tomcat 5.5.27

Answer (score 1):

Authentication is there only if you configure it yourself. By default web applications do not use authentication.

Answer (score 0):

But if, as I suspect, you didn't put it there yourself, it would have been helpful for you to be told where to look.  In Java, at any rate, there is probably a web.xml file in a source directory (WEB_INF/).